# Does SQL Native Client come with SQL Server 2014 LocalDB?

Tags: windows, sql-server-native-client, sql-server-2014-localdb

Does the SQL Server Native Client come with SQL Server 2014 LocalDB?

It is unclear due to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280510.aspx...

Do we have install it separately and if yes suggest the link, please.